# Java wierd error when trying to load image

Tags: java

I am trying to load an image using

```
static Image terrain = null;
```

Followed by

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arcanus arc = new Arcanus();  
    try {
        terrain = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Arcanus Terrain Tileset.png"));            
        Font customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Golden-Sun.ttf")).deriveFont(12f);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Golden-Sun.ttf")));
        arc.setFont(customFont);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I get the following error

```
Uncompilable source code - non-static method getClass() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I have no idea why its doing this any help would be apreciated

Comment: Could you please post a little more of the source?

Comment: Change `getClass()` to `YourClassNameHere.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling

```
terrain = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Arcanus Terrain Tileset.png"));
```

inside a static method. You cannot call `getClass()` inside a static method since `getClass()` refers to an instance of a class. In that context you should call:

```
terrain = ImageIO.read(MyClass.class.getResource("Arcanus Terrain Tileset.png"));
```